# RSA - Math.pow inaccurate

Tags: c#, math, rsa, pow

I am trying to use the RSA algorithm for learning purposes. Now I have the following issue. I stuck at the following point.

i need to solve the following function:

```
c = value^e % n
```

c = encrypted result
value = the number to be encrypted
d = my public key
n = RSA module

I only use double as a datatype for all variables. The function I solved with the following line:

```
double c = Math.Pow(value, e) % n
```

The issue here is, that it looks like the math.pow function produces a wrong value, it seems like it a bit inaccurate. When I try this with the Windows calculator I get a much better result which is correct.

My questions: Does someone know, how to solve this to get the correct result to work with RSA. The calculation of all teh other parts is definetly correct. It only can be the math.pow or the modulus thing.

Comment: You can't use floating-point for RSA. You need `BigInteger`s

Answer (score 3):

You're using a floating point function for something that should really be done using arbitrary precision integers.

Comment: Which datatype do you think should I use. As far as I know, Math.pow only works with double datatype. Any suggestions? Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm not a C# expert.  In his answer, Enigmativity Suggests `System.Numerics.BigInteger`

Answer (score 1):

If you add a reference to `System.Numerics.dll` (in .NET 4.0) you can use the new `System.Numerics.BigInteger` structure that will allow integer operations without any fear of performing and overflow operation. You can easily then implement power in terms of `BigInteger` which will be accurate.

Comment: He just needs to use `BigInteger.ModPow` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.modpow.aspx

Comment: @CodeInChaos Doesn't ModPow defeat the learning aspect? (But thanks for finding this. Of course, there will already be a library function to do what he wants. +1 for being the first to mention it.)

Comment: @UncleO: Possibly, but I don't think so since the OP wasn't really trying to implement modular exponentiation in his original code.

Answer (score 0):

Writing a method to calculate the power of arbitrary precision numbers isn't all that hard, just use Decimal datatype and you should be ok.

Comment: Decimal doesn't work for RSA either. Decimal is 128bit, for RSA you need 1024 to 4096 bits.

Answer (score 0):

Perform all the computation in integers.

Raising to the power becomes multiplying by value in a loop e times. Perform a % operation within the loop to avoid overflow.

You may be able to avoid the % operator by substituting a while loop to reduce the result to below n. (% operators are generally very slow. If speed is not an issue, go ahead an use it.)

```
c = 1;
for (int i = e; i--; i > 0)
{
    c *= value;
    while ( c > n) { c -= n; }
}
```

Comment: Don't you think it is a *bit* small for RSA?

Comment: It's a learning exercise. If he wants to modify it to handle longer lengths, he can. The main point is that he should be using this algorithm in integer types, rather than floating point, and that the mod operation should be used each iteration, rather than at the end.

Comment: looping e times doesn't work in your lifetime for big integers :-) There is a much better way where you square or multiply depending on each bit of the exponent. Reducing mod N at each step is also critical.